# How to pass on an "javascript-edited" image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I just want to start out by saying that I have no knowledge of javascript or its relatives. I have just copied the code I'm working with. With that said, lets move on.

**What I must achieve:**
When a user enters a page, they need to set markers on an image displayed on the page and submit a form.

**What I have done so far:**
- Set a marker on the image wherever clicked
- Store the x-y-coordinates for this marker
- Remove a marker if clicked on

**What I need your help with:**
- Remove the stored x-y-coordinates for the removed marker

**The code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 8;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop - 8;

    $("#img_val").val(function(index, val) {
      return val + "(" + (x + 8) + "-" + (y + 8) + ")";
    });

    $('<img/>').click(function() {
      $(this).remove();
      return false;
    }).attr({
      src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/NotCommons-emblem-copyrighted.svg/50px-NotCommons-emblem-copyrighted.svg.png',
      'class': 'added_image',
      id: $("img.added_image").length + 1
    }).
    css({
      'top': y,
      'left': x,
      'z-index': '10'
    }).appendTo('#target');
  });
})
```

```css
#target {
  position: relative;
  width: px;
}

.added_image {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="Some useful text here" />
</div>

<!-- This is where I store the x-y-coordinates -->
<!-- On the real page it's type is "hidden" -->
<input type="text" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" style="width: 90%;" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3675/

Comment: Maybe you can store generated id and position of every marker into array instead of just append position into input. That will be easier to manage.

Comment: I would agree, but I dunno how to do that =(